# How can i solve using Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++

here is a link to spoj problem [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CPCRC1C/)

I m beginner in solving Dp problems..

Though i found some pattern ..But i m not able to put it in an efficient manner..

I tried the naive approach but this surely will give TLE .

```
void cal(int *a,int n)
{
    while(n!=0)
    {
         a[n%10]++;
         n/=10;
    }
}

void print(int *a)
{
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
    {
            ans+=i*a[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n",ans);
}
```

And then subtracting the sum of smaller no from larger number..And adding sum of digits of lower limit..
i.e    if a=12 b=15

sum1=51
sum2=66

ans=66-51+(sum of digits of 12=1+2)=15+3=18

Any help will be beneficial..Thanx in advance.

Comment: One tip: write a function `f` to calculate sum of digits up to `a` and then print the sum of the digits in [a,b] as `f(b) - f(a-1)`

Comment: yeah i did the same thing..But it will give TLE..as numbers are too large!!And it will take a lot of time..

Comment: I never said **how** you write this function. You can make a solution that works for way bigger values of n than the constraints. I have solved this problem for n <= 10^1000000.

Comment: can u give some hint on writing that function?

Comment: Try to write a function that counts how many times you ave 1 for units digit, how many times for tens and so on. Then generalize the function to work for the other digits. For each digit multiply the number of its occurrences by its value. Accumulate those and voila you have your answer.

Comment: Yeah someone got an idea...Though i did this..But try to think on more on that..Well thanx a lot Ivaylo Strandjev..

Comment: I will post later my comment as an answer because I really hate threads on SoF that have no answer and it turns out what I am looking for can be found in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving the whole problem for you I will try to give you a few tips:

- Don't write a function that computes the sum in interval `[a,b]` instead write a function that computes the sum in the interval `[0,x]` and than you have:

  ```
  SUM([a,b]) = SUM([0, b]) - SUM([0, a-1])
  ```
- In order to compute the sum of digits up to a given limit `L`, for each digit `d` compute how many times it is met as a digit in all the numbers up to `L`. To do that compute how many times `d` appears as units digit, how many times it appears as tens digit and so on.

Comment: _Awesome_...Thanx..Got it!!Will try to code now!!Sorry I dont have reputation ..Cant vote your answer!!:(